# Custom Exception handling in Rest client using Rest Template

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate, spring-restcontroller

I Did Custom Exception handling on server side using **@ControllerAdvice** and extending **ResponseEntityExceptionHandler** . I have a requirement to call the service from rest client using rest template. Rest template uses **DefaultResponseErrorHandler** class for exception handling. Please provide me the sample or document to create exception handling on rest client side.

Comment: This link may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37584379/unmarshalling-response-depending-on-http-code-during-spring-rest-service-call/37587332#37587332

Comment: Can I able to redirect all exceptions to server ? Because I in server ResponseEntityExceptionHandler  class handles all the exceptions, If so tell me how ? If wrong thinking , please provide me good way of handling exceptions in rest template client side.

Comment: you need this error handler on the client side to manage server exceptions. you'll have to create a logic to check the server message from the response and act accordingly. So, on server side when  exception occurs you'll have to create a json error message and add it to the response. On client side you'll deserailize the json error message and comvert them back to your exception objects.

Comment: Client must know what the exception is through  xml or json format with status code and exception message.

Comment: yes updated the last comment.